# Deployment of Sitecore 7 into Azure PaaS

Tags: deployment, paas

We have doubt regarding, deploying Sitecore version 7 site to Azure Paas?

As per in the sitecore documentation, We have explored that Sitecore Experience Platform support Azure Paas from sitecore 8.0+ versions.

Kindly reply back to us, if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - NO, Sitecore 7 is not supprted on Azure PaaS.

From Sitecore XP 8.2 Update-1 (rev. 161115) supports deployments to Microsoft Azure using the Web Apps feature in Azure App Service.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can run Sitecore 7 on Azure Classic (aka old PaaS) with worker roles. But I would not recommend it...